# libreoffice java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when installing an extension

Tags: java, python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04, extension-methods, libreoffice

When installing an extension I've used on many systems, I got java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException error installing on Ubuntu 18.

Comment: Same error message when trying to install the Zotero plugin on LibreOffice for Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I found the following at https://github.com/zotero/zotero-libreoffice-integration/issues/57:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-java-common
```

The LibreOffice that comes with Ubuntu 18 seems to be trim lined. In addition to adding the java common, I need to add python to be able to write macros in python3. FYI: to added python use:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-script-provider-python
```

as shown on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325163/missing-python-in-libreoffice-organize-macros-menu).